# Recommendation for small lightbox script to refresh internal div

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, css

There is a piece of functionality that I am trying to emulate on a .net e-commerce site, where you have a target area (I'll use the term "window" here, but I'm not talking about an actual window, more a div) which contains a large image. Next to the large image container, there are several smaller thumbnails. I want to emulate the functionality where as you either mouseover or click on the thumbnails, it refreshes the larger window with the fullsize version of that thumbnail. I guess it's a lightbox at the end of the day.

This isnt one of those cases where I've googled around and can't find any solutions... actually the polar opposite, i've found too many of them. I'm asking the community if there is any prebuilt script that is better than the others, or if anyone has done anything custom like this that's easy to implement. We aren't talking about pages of thumbnails here, maybe 2-3 per image. Again, I'm not trying to pop it in a lightbox, but refresh a div thats already inside the page.

Answer (score 1):

What is structure of those divs?

If I get it right. Each thumb has responding to it 'big div' that is shown when clicked.

I would join then each small div with big via and attach action:

```
var b1 = $('#big1');
$('#small1').data('big',b1).click(function(){
    var big = $(this).data('big');
    big.someShowFunction();
});
```

Comment: I understand the direction you're going in with this. To be honest, its not set in stone yet. I kept it deliberately vague because if there was an "out of the box" script that did what I wanted, I didn't want to have to undo a bunch of custom coding. Let me experiment a bit with this approach.